# How to Android Holo Theme style dialog box buttons

Tags: android, android-theme

I'm creating a Dialog Box on Holo Theme and want to follow the OS default way of displaying the buttons. So far I have created the dialog box but the buttons don't render in the way it does in the apps done in Holo for ICS.
How can I do this?
My intended look & feel is
[image: No. 3rd in this image]
and I am able to reach till here
[image: Notice the Signup and Login buttons]

Answer (score 85, accepted):

a bit late, but maybe someone is still interested in that.

this works pretty good for me.

```
...
<!--
EDIT: be carefull, "?android:attr/dividerHorizontal" is only supported since API 11
      just avoid it in prior OSs.
-->
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:background="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal" />
<LinearLayout 
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="0dip"
    android:paddingLeft="2dip"
    android:paddingRight="2dip"
    android:measureWithLargestChild="true">

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/cancel"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@android:string/cancel"/>
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/ok"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@android:string/ok"/>
</LinearLayout>
...
```

the activity that loads this layout needs the Holo.Dialog theme.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog"
```

Comment: Small correction: probably you should use dividerHorizontal in the very first view in your example.

Comment: be carefull, dividerHorizontal isn't supported prior API 11.

Comment: @dimsuz Why the `dividerHorizontal`?

Comment: @KevinOrr look at the screenshot in the question at the top: this is the divider which is above OK|Cancel buttons and it is a horizontal one. IIRC this answer had dividerVertical when first posted, but author has edited it since then and now everything's fine :)

Comment: @dimsuz I was trying it out in Eclipse and taking it out didn't seem to change anything.  What's it doing?

Answer (score 21):

This is what works:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonHolder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cmdSignup"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button.Borderless.Small"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/Signup" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cmdLogin"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button.Borderless.Small"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/Login" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The property `style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button.Borderless.Small"` gives the flat look and feel, and the 50% weight distribution is because of combining 100$ sizing of `LinearLayout` by `android:layout_width="match_parent" and`android:layout_weight="1"`for buttons

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just wondering how or if you were able to get the light grey border around the buttons as shown in your first screenshot? Thanks

Comment: I didn't get it with this markup alone.  I was in a rush.. very bad rush to complete the project and I didn't care to see why I didn't get it and I didn't correct it.  In a weeks time, they asked to shift it from ICS to GB and I had to manually create all this so effort wasted and long forgotten :)

Comment: but yeah, if I had to do it again, I'd go to download one of the examples from Android Dev site and check it out

Comment: You shouldn't be referencing the style directly, use `style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"` Which is used in the docs http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html

Comment: This could be grate, but this requires API Level 14 for this style. Do you have solution if the backward compatibility matters?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the theme through the Android Manifest xml or inside the Activity's onCreate with `setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Holo);`

The buttons size is not related to the theme itself. The size is up to your xml definitions.
In the image you sent, it seems that the buttons received the Holo theme so there's nothing wrong here...

Here's an xml layout that will stretch the buttons to fill the whole dialog width:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                >
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/okButton"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="OK"
                />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Cancel"
                />          
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this doesn't work.  I agree about the width, but I cannot get the flat look of the button on the dialog box

Comment: @kishu27 So the XML i wrote here fixed the buttons width but the buttons still don't get the Holo theme flat layout?

Comment: sadly not even the width :) I'm sorry.. I found out about the flat button style and will post the answer as soon as I fix the width issue.  Strangely, your code should have worked but it isnt working and I can't think of anything else for the width

Comment: I think it the width worked fine as soon as I changed `fill_parent` to `match_parent`

Comment: @kishu27 cool. at least my answer gave you the right direction :) glad you solve it.