# Change color of blue line under title view in dialogpreference

Tags: android, dialog, settings, color-scheme, preference

Is there a way to change the color of the blue line under the title in a DialogPreference to a color like yellow or orange?  I've tried:

1. Changing the themes for AlertDialogs manually
2. Using the `project: android-styled-dialogs` library
3. Subclassing DialogPreference and adding a `customTitleView` with an orange drawable that's 2dp wide in `onPrepareDialogBuilder(Builder builder)`. (See [android Theme.Holo.Dialog changing blue lines to orange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057859/android-theme-holo-dialog-changing-blue-lines-to-orange))

None of these attempts have been successful. Has anyone had experience with this and found a solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439538/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-alertdialog-title-and-the-color-of-the-line-under), which has a good answer

Comment: Already tried that and Joseph Earl's solution.  Doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out, but its a hacky solution.  For DialogPreferences, the AlertDialog.Builder methods aren't called until showDialog() (see [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/preference/DialogPreference.java#DialogPreference.showDialog%28android.os.Bundle%29)).

Knowing that and modifying the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439538/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-alertdialog-title-and-the-color-of-the-line-under?lq=1), we can get rid of the title with the 
Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE flag and inflate our own XML with a title and our own horizontal divider built-int:

```
@Override
    protected void showDialog(Bundle state) {
        Context context = getContext();        
        AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.pref_dialog_about_title, null);

        onBindDialogView(view);
        mBuilder.setView(view);
        onPrepareDialogBuilder(mBuilder);

//        getPreferenceManager().registerOnActivityDestroyListener();

        // Create the dialog
        final Dialog dialog = mBuilder.create();
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        if (state != null) {
            dialog.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
        }

        dialog.setOnDismissListener(this);
        dialog.show();

        Button neutralButton = ((AlertDialog)dialog).getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);
        FontChanger.getInstance(getContext()).changeFont(neutralButton);
        neutralButton.setTextColor(mColorOrangeEnabled);
        neutralButton.setBackgroundDrawable(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ab_background_gradient_bottom));
    }
```

where `onBindDialogView(View view)` simply locates the TextViews (title and message) and initializes them. `onPrepareDialogBuilder()` just calls setNeutralButton(...).

pref_dialog_about_title.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/title_template"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/ab_background_gradient_top">
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/alertTitle"
            style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="9dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/border">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/author"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/btag"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/author"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

ab_background_gradient_top:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Bottom Line -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/orange" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Color of your action bar -->
    <item android:bottom="2dip">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
            android:angle="90"
            android:centerColor="#3b0808"
            android:endColor="#570b0b"
            android:startColor="#1d0404"
            android:type="linear" />

            <corners 
                android:radius="0dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```